# Parse the elements of a flat array and group related data sets

Tags: php, arrays, dataset, grouping, text-parsing

I need to extract the recurring sets of values for `Title`, `Album`, and `Artist` coming from a flat array of strings.

Notice that the `file:` prefixed element represents the start of a new set of data.

Sample input:

```
$playlistid = [
    'MPD 0.23.5',
    'file: Blondie/Parallel_Lines/12_Just_Go_Away.flac',
    'Last-Modified: 2016-06-05T17:15:07Z',
    'Format: 44100:16:2',
    'Album: Parallel Lines',
    'AlbumArtist: Blondie',
    'Artist: Blondie',
    'Composer: Debbie Harry',
    'Date: 1978',
    'Genre: Rock',
    'Title: Just Go Away',
    'Track: 12',
    'Time: 214',
    'duration: 213.800',
    'Pos: 0',
    'Id: 745',
    'file: Blondie/Parallel_Lines/13_Once_I_Had_a_Love-aka_The_Disco_Song-1978_version-.flac',
    'Last-Modified: 2016-06-05T17:15:01Z',
    'Format: 44100:16:2',
    'Album: Parallel Lines',
    'AlbumArtist: Blondie',
    'Artist: Blondie',
    'Composer: Chris Stein; Debbie Harry',
    'Date: 1978',
    'Genre: Rock',
    'Title: Once I Had a Love (aka The Disco Song) (1978 version)',
    'Track: 13',
    'Time: 198',
    'duration: 198.000',
    'Pos: 1',
    'Id: 746',
    'file: Blondie/Parallel_Lines/14_Bang_a_Gong-Get_It_On-live-.flac',
    'Last-Modified: 2016-06-05T17:15:03Z',
    'Format: 44100:16:2',
    'Album: Parallel Lines',
    'AlbumArtist: Blondie',
    'Artist: Blondie',
    'Composer: Marc Bolan',
    'Date: 1978',
    'Genre: Rock',
    'Title: Bang a Gong (Get It On) (live)',
    'Track: 14',
    'Time: 330',
    'duration: 330.293',
    'Pos: 2',
    'Id: 747',
    ''
];
```

I have a foreach loop that searches the above array for the desired fields, and generates three arrays with the desired keys.

```
foreach($playlistid as $key => $value) {
    if (preg_match('/\bTitle:\s/', $value)) {
        $song_title = $playlistid[$key];
    }
    if (preg_match('/\bArtist:\s/', $value)) {
        $song_artist = $playlistid[$key];
    }
    if (preg_match('/\bAlbum:\s/', $value)) {
        $album_title = $playlistid[$key]
    }
}
```

The result I'm looking for, is the output to look like this:

```
Artist, Album, Title

Blondie Parallel Lines Just Go Away
Blondie Parallel Lines Once I Had a Love (aka The Disco Song) (1978 version)
Blondie Parallel Lines Bang a Gong (Get It On) (live)
```

It's worth bearing in mind that with a various album for example, the Artist and Album tags will also change with each new track.

Comment: That's too much for one question. And irrelevant title on top of that. Try to focus on exactly one problem, be it input parsing, output formatting or function parameters

Comment: I was trying to offer as much info as possible, as I thought without the initial array and code explaining how I have arrived where I am, most of the question wouldn't make sense. @RiggsFolly Thanks for adding the code tags to the last paragraph, I had overlooked that.

Comment: Your approach is honestly too much. I'd just do it in a single loop instead. Keep 3 booleans for each data type you're looking for. Like `$titleFound`,`$artistFound` and `$albumFound`. When you found one, store the data and set the corresponding boolean to true. If all 3 are found, combine the data correctly and save in an array. Reset the booleans and keep going. Once the loop is finished, return the array with all the results and you're done

Comment: @icecub you are probably correct, and this is my amateur approach to PHP on show here. I lack sufficient knowledge to take the approach you suggest. Perhaps I should delete my question..

Comment: _"as they appear multiple times"_ - but always in the same order, it appears? If that can be considered guaranteed, then you could simply assume that when you come across a `Title` record, you must have found the other two before already - so at that point you could simply write all three found values into an array then, and proceed with the next set ...

Comment: @CBroe That's exactly what I meant, though I'd use booleans with it for error handling. Just in case that order isn't guaranteed

Comment: @CBroe they appear in the same order, but sometimes there are additional fields in between. Also, array_search doesn't work, as it relies on an exact match being found - so although 'Title:' appears multiple times, it's actually 'Title: song1', 'Title: song2' etc. so array_search simply doesn't 'see' it.

Comment: _"but sometimes there are additional fields in between"_ - that doesn't matter much, since none of the conditions inside your loop would match for any of those other rose to begin with.

Comment: I've edited the post - the comments made me realise I was overthinking (and over complicating) this.

Answer (score 0):

1. Iterate over the payload.
2. Every time a `file` label is encountered, create a new reference variable and push it into the result array.
3. If an `Artist`, `Album`, or `Title` label is encountered, push that value into the reference variable.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/EmgCJ))

```
function parse(array $lines): array
{
    $result = [];
    foreach ($lines as $line) {
        $split = explode(': ', $line, 2);
        switch ($split[0]) {
            case 'file':
                unset($ref);
                $ref = [null, null, null];
                $result[] = &$ref;
                break;
            case 'Artist':
                $ref[0] = $split[1];
                break;
            case 'Album':
                $ref[1] = $split[1];
                break;
            case 'Title':
                $ref[2] = $split[1];
                break;
        }
    }
    return $result;
}
```

Presenting your data to the end user will be a trivial matter now that the data has been parsed and a multidimensional array has been populated.

Comment: thanks for this. I will have to revisit my code, because if I remember my code correctly, your solution looks a lot simpler compared to what I eventually came up with.